# Google.Apis.Auth.OAuth2.Mvc How to make callback with HTTPS (C#)

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, google-oauth

I implemented Google OAUTH used google API:

```
    AuthorizationCodeMvcApp authorizationCodeMvcApp = new AuthorizationCodeMvcApp(controller, flowData);
    AuthorizationCodeWebApp.AuthResult authorizationResult = await authorizationCodeMvcApp.AuthorizeAsync(CancellationToken.None);
```

with custom FlowMetadata where override:

```
public override string AuthCallback
{
   get
   {                
      string controllerName = nameof(BillsEmailsConfigurationController);
      controllerName = SubstringController(controllerName);
      string actionName = "Callback";                
      return $"/{controllerName}/{actionName}";
   }
}
```

everything works fine but in the production Server, we have a load balancing where the local protocol is HTTP, and only outside we use HTTPS, how to force to put HTTPS prefix to callback for google OAuth API?
ps. return full URL like 'https://..../Callback' doesn't work

Answer (score 1):

Found out the solution is to write custom AuthorizationCodeMvcApp that implemented from AuthorizationCodeWebApp here is the source https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-dotnet-client/blob/master/Src/Support/Google.Apis.Auth.Mvc/OAuth2/Mvc/AuthorizationCodeMvcApp.cs

and in line #46 you can see the passing of the full callback URL